# round() not displaying digits

Tags: r, precision, rounding

When I read in data that has a few digits after the decimal place, I notice that R doesn't give me the full value when I ask for it, even when I use round(). Any ideas what could be going on? Here are some example data:

```
test <- data.frame("A"=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), "B"=c(0.254, 0.457, 0.123, 1.089), "C"=c(101.1, 101.2, 354.1234, 354.1235))
```

When I enter:

```
test[1,2]
```

the output is 0.254. But when I try to see the same thing from the 3rd column, where I have numbers with digits in the hundreds place out to the millionths place (i.e. XXX.XXXX), the output doesn't give me any numbers after the decimal place. For example, when I enter:

```
test[3,3]
```

the output is 354.

When I try:

```
round(test[3,3], digits=4)
```

I *still* get 354. But when I subtract like this:

```
test[3,3]-test[4,3]
```

the output is 0.0001. What is going on here and how can I see 4 digits after the decimal when I ask for them?

Comment: is this matlab or what?

Comment: Check the structure of your data using (str). It may accidentally have converted to type int. Also play with options(scipen = xx) where xx is  up to you. Try maybe 4-5 in there.

Comment: `test[3,3]` gives me `[1] 354.1234` (so do all the other commands). It might be some options settings in your R session. BTW my `options("scipen")` is `0` `options("digits")` is `7`(if that helps)

Comment: Also check the value of `options("digits")`.  You may have re-set the default on accident.

Comment: Thank you FrankP. @rmk, and RScriv! Somehow, my digits got set to 3! That solved my problem. Is there any way to permanently set the options so that I can keep using the set of options I like every time I open a new R session?

Comment: @alex9311: Sorry, I should have put in the title that it's a question about R. I did tag it, but the title would have made it immediately clear. Thanks!

Comment: Right... it's R but you have already gotten messages saying your istallation is not responding hte same way as `others`. You may have `options()` set differently and you are not providing _any_ information about your setup. You can set options() in .Rprofile. Look at ?Startup